# Axios in laravel package with sanctum not setting cookie on request

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-sanctum

I'm building a Laravel 8 package to use in my Laravel 8 project, using laravel sanctum 2.x, I've set my project to use my custom package's models and user `CmsUser` and have:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

window.axios = axios
```

My cookies are present in my browser, the session and token cookies but I don't see them on my requests

What am I missing

[image]

Comment: Does the session cookie have any domain restriction by any chance?

Comment: Nope, everything configured as per the docs

Comment: I believe laravel sets a domain on the session_cookie by default